# Python - checking if all tasks from a Queue are completed

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Is there an option to check if a Queue is empty AND all Threads have already finished processing their tasks (i.e. task_done() was run)? I want to add additional tasks only if both conditions are met.

As I want to be able to add more tasks I cannot just quit unused threads and use activeCount(). Also I don't want to join() the Queue as I want to be able to actively monitor progress of the execution.

Here is an example code:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

queue = Queue()

def my_method(queue):
    while True:
        task = queue.get()

        time.sleep((task + 2) * 3)

        queue.task_done()

num_queue_threads = 2
queue_threads = [None] * num_queue_threads

for i in range(num_queue_threads):
    queue_threads[i] = Thread(target=my_method, args=(queue,))
    queue_threads[i].setDaemon(True)
    queue_threads[i].start()

for task in range(3):
    queue.put(task)

#queue.join() #need to wait actively

while True:
    print("queue.qsize(): {}, queue.empty(): {}".format(queue.qsize(), queue.empty()))

    time.sleep(1)
```

Queue is empty as soon as the execution of the last task STARTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no public interface for this. Someone's probably going to post a fragile solution poking at the internal attribute the queue uses to track unfinished tasks, but seriously, don't do that. That attribute isn't part of the documented API, and it could be renamed or redesigned in a future version.

Just track task completion yourself. One option would be to have a separate queue where the workers can send "task complete" messages to the orchestrator, and the orchestrator waits until it's received a number of messages equal to the number of tasks it assigned:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time

task_queue = Queue()
completion_queue = Queue()

def my_method(in_queue, out_queue):
    while True:
        task = in_queue.get()
        time.sleep((task + 2) * 3)
        in_queue.task_done()

        # Send completion message
        out_queue.put(task)

num_queue_threads = 2
queue_threads = [None] * num_queue_threads

for i in range(num_queue_threads):
    queue_threads[i] = Thread(target=my_method, args=(task_queue, completion_queue))
    queue_threads[i].setDaemon(True)
    queue_threads[i].start()

for task in range(3):
    task_queue.put(task)

for _ in range(3):
    completion_queue.get()
    completion_queue.task_done()
    print("One task done!")

print("All done!")
```

Comment: The only problem here is that I cannot control how long the completion_queue.get() takes, so I may not be able to perform any periodical activities. But at least I know there is no other recommended way to track unfinished tasks. I will probably switch my logic to use task statuses from sqlite instead (as I already use this db for storing their metadata). Thanks!

Comment: Also - I could run completion_queue.get() with a timeout, ignore the Empty exception, execute required periodical activities and get back to waiting on the next task.